# isset() not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a search that can query multiple fields - search for a male person who has a hearing aid.

the html code in the form looks like this

```
<form name="O_search" method="post" action="search.php">
Gender (M/F)<input type="text" name="O_gender"/>
Hearing Aid (Y/N)<input type="text"  name="O_hear"/>


<input type="hidden" name="O_searching" value="yes" />
```

the php code looks like this

```
if (isset($_POST['O_searching'] )) 
{ 
    echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>"; 


    if (isset($_POST['O_gender']) || isset($_POST['O_hear']) == "") 
    { 
        echo "You forgot to enter a search term"; 
        exit; 
    } 
    $Gender =$_POST['O_gender']; 
    $Hear =$_POST['O_hear'];

    $Gender = strtoupper($Gender); 
    $Gender = strip_tags($Gender); 
    $Gender = trim ($Gender); 

    $Hear = strtoupper($Hear); 
    $Hear = strip_tags($Hear); 
    $Hear = trim ($Hear);

    $Odata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM p_candidate WHERE(`gender` LIKE '%".$Gender."%') AND (`hear`  LIKE '%".$Hear."%')") or die(mysql_error());

    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($Odata)) 
    {
        $candidate_id =$result['candidate_id'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href ='opening_candidatepage.php?id=$candidate_id'>".$result['R_first_name']."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$result['R_last_name']."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>".$result['R_county']."</td>"; 

     } 

     $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($Odata); 
     if ($anymatches == 0) 
     { 
         echo "Sorry, there is no match for your query<br><br>"; 
     } 

     echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$Gender."&nbsp;&nbsp;and".$Hear ; 
 }
 ?>
```

I don't know where I have gone wrong, but even when I enter a valid search term in the field I get the message 
You forgot to enter a search term

Comment: `isset($_POST['O_hear']) == ""` - you don't need the comparison there, just `isset($_POST['O_hear'])` will do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are causing the error condition if the value IS set. You want to trigger the error when it is NOT set.

```
if( !isset($_POST['O_gender']) || !isset($_POST['O_hear']))
```

Comment: Thank you so much ... it worked !!! Magnificent ...

Answer (score 1):

Instaed of this line,

```
if (isset($_POST['O_gender']) || isset($_POST['O_hear']) == "")
```

try this one

```
if (!isset($_POST['O_gender']) || !isset($_POST['O_hear']))
```

Answer (score 0):

A text field will always be set in a form, even if a blank string. You should use isset for best practices, but also use strlen and trim to see if the string contained anything. You also want to only display the error message when there IS NO string.

`if(!isset($_POST['O_hear']) || strlen(trim($_POST['O_hear'])) == 0)`

Do that for both terms if needed. It's a little unclear what you're trying to do.